# Trying to move one option to another select list

Tags: javascript

I've tried searching this and all the answers are way above my head, and are just confusing and frustrating me... All I'm trying to do is make an option from the left list that is selected, move to the right list when I click a button. This is the script I'm attempting to use, and it isn't working for me...

```
function moveRight() {
var selItem = document.forms[0].leftList.selectedIndex;

 if (selItem == -1) {
  window.alert("You must first select an item on the left side.")
 }

 else {
  var selText = document.forms[0].leftList[selItem].text;
  var selValue = document.forms[0].leftList[selItem].value;
  var nextItem = document.forms[0].rightList.length;

  document.forms[0].rightList[nextItem].text = selText;
  document.forms[0].rightList[nextItem].value = selValue;
 }
}
```

Any thoughts on how to make this work without over-complicating the matter?

Comment: can you please also share a snippet of your html? it would be helpful to see the markup of your form.

Comment: It's hard to copy paste, since I'm posting from a different computer, but I'll give some example of my html...

    <select name = "leftList" size = "10">
     <option value = "example">Example</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="&#62;&#62;" onclick =     "moveRight();" />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were three problems in your code:

1. Use `document.getElementById` instead of `document.forms[0].leftList`
2. Use `cloneNode` and `removeChild` and `appendChild` to move your elements around
3. I didn't see any place you were calling your function `moveRight`. Had to add an `onchange` event

Sample code:

```
function moveRight() {
    var leftlist = document.getElementById("leftList");
    var selItem = leftlist.selectedIndex;

    if (selItem == -1) {
        window.alert("You must first select an item on the left side.")
    } else {
        var rightlist = document.getElementById("rightList");
        var newOption = leftlist[selItem].cloneNode(true);

        leftlist.removeChild(leftlist[selItem]);
        rightlist.appendChild(newOption);
    }
}

document.getElementById('leftList').onchange = moveRight;
```

Comment: I'll give this a try, see if I can make it work for me, thanks.

Edit: Well, after trying the code this way, and adding the appropriate id tags to my html, it seems to work, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using one of the common js libraries (Mootools/jQuery)?
If not, read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild 
At the end there is a link on how to remove a dom element, and the link I gave you, is how to attach the dom element where u need to.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
var nextItem = document.forms[0].rightList.length;

document.forms[0].rightList[nextItem].text = selText;
document.forms[0].rightList[nextItem].value = selValue;
```

to

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = selValue;
option.text = selText;

document.forms[0].rightList.appendChild(option);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways of doing what you are trying to achieve. I don't know your requirements that's why I tried to keep the code as close to what you tried as possible.

```
function moveRight() {
    var selItem = document.forms[0].leftList.selectedIndex;
    if (selItem == -1) {
        window.alert("You must first select an item on the left side.")
    } else {
        document.forms[0].rightList.add(document.forms[0].leftList[selItem], null);
    }
}
```

Check it on http://jsfiddle.net/Z8xRp/3/

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit late but here is a solution ( move between multiple selects ) i just changed some lines from an older solution

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/rTxb8/

```
    function moveRight() {
    var selItem = document.forms[0].leftList.selectedIndex;
    if (selItem == -1) {
        window.alert("You must first select an item on the left side.")
    } else {
        document.forms[0].rightList.add(document.forms[0].leftList[selItem], null);
    }
}

function moveLeft() {
    var selItem = document.forms[0].rightList.selectedIndex;
    if (selItem == -1) {
        window.alert("You must first select an item on the left side.")
    } else {
        document.forms[0].leftList.add(document.forms[0].rightList[selItem], null);
    }
}
```