# How to use cloneNode & appendChild methods in svg scripting?

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

My question is about how to use methods of the Node Object in svg scripting?
I searched for the answer like [How do I use javascript to clone an SVG element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091555/how-do-i-use-javascript-to-clone-an-svg-element) and [Trying to move one option to another select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719768/trying-to-move-one-option-to-another-select-list) but it didn't work for me. I want to join two lists of svg elements in a group. here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<svg version="1.1" id="my_svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 900">
<g id="blocks">
<rect x="941.616" y="35.935" width="26.5" height="26.5"/>
<polygon points="936.717,62.391 936.717,62.391 936.717,62.391 936.717,35.934 910.261,35.934 910.261,35.935 
910.261,35.935 910.26,35.935 910.26,62.391 910.261,62.391 936.717,62.391 "/>
<rect x="741.162" y="120.203" width="26.5" height="26.5"/>
<polygon points="736.263,146.66 736.263,146.659 736.263,146.659 736.263,120.203 709.807,120.203 709.807,120.203 
709.806,120.203 709.806,120.203 709.806,146.66 709.806,146.66 736.263,146.66 "/>
...
</g>
</svg>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
var list_a = [];
var new_list = document.getElementById("blocks");
var rects = new_list.getElementsByTagName("rect");
var polygons = new_list.getElementsByTagName("polygon");
var length = rects.length + polygons.length;
list_a = rects.cloneNode(true);
polygons.appendChild(list_a);
console.log(list_a.length);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you'll have to loop through the nodeList elements, you can't call directly `cloneNode()` on the nodeList

Comment: you mean I have to use their childNodes?

Comment: no, `getElementsByTagName()` will return a nodeList, an Array-like object containing all the matched elements. You will have to loop through this nodeList to touch the contained nodes. Those nodes have a `cloneNode()` property, the list doesn't.