# interchanging all the option from select 1 to select 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the values of list as soon as some one clicks on swap button the link to my code is http://codepen.io/varadekd/pen/OMOYpa

HTML

```
<center>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>list 1 </th>
    <th> list 2 </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="mySelect1" size="5" multiple style="width:200px">
        <option value="opt1">First item of list 1</option>
        <option value="opt2">Second item of list 1</option>
        <option value="opt3">Thrid item of list 1</option>
        <option value="opt4">Fourth item of list 1</option>
        <option value="opt5">Fifth item of list 1</option>
      </select>
    </td>

    <td>
      <select id="mySelect2" size="5" multiple style="width:200px">
        <option value="opt6">First item of list 2</option>
        <option value="opt7">Second item of list 2</option>
        <option value="opt8">Thrid item of list 2</option>
        <option value="opt9">Fourth item of list 2</option>
        <option value="opt10">Fifth item of list 2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table> 
</center>
<center>
  <button id="toRight">Swap to list 1</button>

  <button id="toLeft"> Swap to list 2</button> <br/>

  <button id="swipe"> Swap </button>
<input type="button" onClick="count1()" value="Item in list 1" />
<input type="button" onClick="count2()" value="Item in list 2" />
 </center>
```

JS

```
    $(function () { 
  function moveItems(origin, dest) {
    $(origin).find(':selected').appendTo(dest);
}

$('#toLeft').click(function () {
    moveItems('#mySelect1', '#mySelect2');
});

$('#toRight').on('click', function () {
    moveItems('#mySelect2', '#mySelect1');
});
});

function count1(){
  var store = $('select#mySelect1 option').length;
  alert(store);
}

function count2(){
  var store2 = $('select#mySelect2 option').length;
  alert(store2);
}
```

I that i have to move all the option from list 1 to list 2 and at the same time all the option from list 2 to list 1

Comment: Can you please brief you requirement? Do you want to swap the entire list? or only selected elements?

Comment: See if this helps.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719768/trying-to-move-one-option-to-another-select-list)

Comment: I want to swap entire list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working on your function i have created the following function which will swap the lists.

```
  $('#swipe').on('click', function () {
       $('#mySelect1 option').prop('selected', true); 
     moveItems('#mySelect1', '#mySelect2');   
     $('#mySelect2 option').each(function(){
       if($(this).is(':selected'))
         {
           $(this).prop('selected', false);
         }
       else
         {
            $(this).prop('selected', true);
         }
     });
     moveItems('#mySelect2', '#mySelect1');
     $('#mySelect1 option,#mySelect2 option').prop('selected', false); 
});
```

Working [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxYgpM)

Hope this helps.

-Help :)

Answer (score 2):

One simple way is use following JQuery:

```
$('#swipe').click(function () {

var selOne = $("#mySelect1").html();
var selTwo = $("#mySelect2").html();

$("#mySelect1").html(selTwo);
$("#mySelect2").html(selOne);

});
```

**[Working CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbVGVP)**